# When should I use the “crossorigin” attribute on a “preconnect” <link>?

Tags: html, performance, cross-origin

I’d like to include some preconnect resource hints on my site so that browsers can (for example) connect to the jQuery CDN before they actually see the script tag that invokes the CDN. I’m not sure whether I should include the “crossorigin” attribute or what its value should be. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#preconnect) says, in part,

> To initiate a preconnect, the user agent must run these steps:
>
> […]
>
> 3. Let *corsAttributeState* be the current state of the element's `crossorigin` content attribute.
> 4. Let *credentials* be a boolean value set to `true`.
> 5. If *corsAttributeState* is `Anonymous` and *origin* is not equal to current Document's origin, set credentials to `false`.
> 6. Attempt to obtain connection with *origin* and *credentials*.

I don’t know how to interpret this algorithm. If I’m preconnecting to a CDN, which will let anyone download its content without any sort of credentials, what value should I use for the “crossorigin” attribute?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520102/why-is-preconnect-resource-hint-not-working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the answers so far seem either simplified, incomplete or partially wrong (topic is complex, things are confusingly named and not well documented!), so here's my understanding:

To be able to reuse the connection created by `<link rel=preconnect>`, things depend on what kind of content you want to fetch, from where, whether the request will send browser credentials (which can be established by the browser explicitly or implicitly):

## The request is *same-origin* (`example.com` requests subresource from `example.com`)

There's no need for `preconnect` at all in the first place; the browser keeps the connection open after loading the page for quite a while.
If there are multiple connections to be opened, the browser decides by itself if and how many to open (depending if server announces HTTP/2 support in TLS handshake, browser settings etc.)

*to be checked*: what if same-origin request has `crossorigin` attribute: is it used or ignored?

## The request is *cross-origin* (`example.com` requests subresource from `another.com`)

- if the actual request has `crossorigin` attribute *explicitly set* in HTML (`crossOrigin` in JS - case is important), the preconnect must also have it, with same value *(perhaps except in cases where it doesn't make sense and `crossorigin` is ignored -- not fully clear for me yet)*
- else, if request if for `<script type=module>`: *to be checked*
- else, if request is and "old school" request for `<img>`, `<style type=stylesheet>`, `<iframe>`, classic `<script>` etc. (initiated via HTML or JS)  *without `crossorigin` explicitly specified*, then the preconnect MUST NOT have `crossorigin` attribute set.
- else, if request is a *cross-origin* font request, preconnect must have `crossorigin=anonymous`
- else, if request is a *cross-origin* `fetch` or `XHR`:

  - if it is done in credentialed mode (i.e. cookies are attached or HTTP basic auth is used; in case of fetch, this means `credentials !== omit`; in case of XHR: `withCredentials === true`): preconnect must have `crossorigin=use-credentials`
  - if it is not in credentialed mode: preconnect must have `crossorigin=anonymous`

For the last case (fetch/XHR), go to network panel in Chrome/Firefox devtools, right click a request, and choose `copy as fetch` from a dropdown. This will create a snippet of JS, which will tell you if that request is CORS-enabled (`"mode"=="cors"`) and credentialed (`"credentials"=="include"|"same-origin"`).

Note however the trick above doesn't work correctly for non-XHR/fetch requests, because for example `fetch` and `<img>` use different algorithms to establish connection, as explained before.

Finally, in HTML, `<link ...crossorigin>` === `<link ...crossorigin=anonymous>`.

Additional notes and links:

- in Firefox, [preconnect does not work even if it's supposed to](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1543990)
- [three ways to check if preconnect is working](https://andydavies.me/blog/2019/04/17/three-ways-of-checking-your-rel-equals-preconnect-resource-hints-are-working/)
- [browsers have some limits in how many parallel DNS requests can happen](https://andydavies.me/blog/2019/03/22/improving-perceived-performance-with-a-link-rel-equals-preconnect-http-header/)
- [experimenting with preconnect with custom script injection on WebPageTest](https://andydavies.me/blog/2019/08/07/experimenting-with-link-rel-equals-preconnect-using-custom-script-injection-in-webpagetest/)

Answer (score 7):

I was searching for the same thing and I found [this](https://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/faster-google-webfonts-preconnect/)

It states here that if you don't use cross origin attribute the user agent just does the dns lookup but doesn't establish connection with the particular domain. So crossorigin attribute is needed if you have to preconnect to cross domain, like this:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/" crossorigin>
```

Also if you want to send some credentials to that particular cross domain you can set the value to crossorigin as `crossorigin = use-credentials` otherwise I think the default value is anonymous.

Comment: This is half-true. *If CORS is used* (as it is with fonts), only the DNS lookup will be *used* with the font request. (The connection still happens, but it's not shown in the waterfall chart because [a separate connection must be opened for the CORS request](https://crenshaw.dev/preconnect-resource-hint-crossorigin-attribute).) If you're fetching a script, using `crossorigin` will similarly waste a connection, because a new connection must be opened that *doesn't* use CORS.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on two things:

1. The type of assets to be downloaded (which determines whether CORS will be used)
2. Whether the target server uses credentials for CORS connections

For jQuery, you *would not use `crossorigin`*. Scripts are not among [the types of resources browsers use CORS to download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS).

Fonts, on the other hand, use CORS.

- If the page will only fetch resources that use CORS, include the `crossorigin` attribute.
- If the page will only fetch resources that *don't* use CORS, omit `crossorigin`. If
- If the page will fetch both kinds of resources, [you *may* need two resource hints](https://crenshaw.dev/preconnect-resource-hint-crossorigin-attribute). (Full disclosure, the link is to my personal site. :-)) Someone [pointed out](https://twitter.com/iamakulov/status/1121189614692306944) that you might not need two hints for HTTP/2. I haven't had time to test.

Here's the [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520102/why-is-preconnect-resource-hint-not-working) where I encountered the same issue.

I haven't dived into when CORS credentials are necessary. I haven't seen an example where they're needed, so chances are you're safe with `crossorigin` (i.e. `crossorigin="anonymous").

Answer (score 2):

So far i understand the usage of `crossorigin`, specially in terms of its values `anonymous` and `use-credentials`, you should use `crossorigin="use-credentials"`in case:

- you use assets, like images or videos, which have a crossorigin attribute
- you plan to carry cookies, HTTP authentication, and client-side SSL certificates between origins, based on the user agent's previous interactions with the origin.

Additionally to the documentation cited by you i got [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) and [that](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#user-credentials). But indeed the documentation is misleading and contains misspelling: the first calls it `use-credentials`, the second - `user-credentials`.

Anyway, in my understanding:

- no `crossorigin` at all equals `crossorigin="anonymous"`
- `crossorigin` equals `crossorigin="use-credentials"`

Maybe somebody would correct me.

**PS**: The [current version of Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) to the subject means:

> An invalid keyword and an empty string will be handled as the anonymous keyword.

Means: no `crossorigin` at all, `crossorigin` or `crossorigin="use_credentials"` are all handled as `crossorigin="anonymous"`.

Comment: I believe, as mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes), By default (that is, when the attribute is not specified), CORS is not used at all. Also, setting only `crossorigin` is equal to `crossorigin="anonymous"`.